# How to configure SmtpAppender programmatically in log4j2

Tags: java, log4j2

Following is the code, I am working on :

Purpose is to configure SmtpAppender programmatically. Along  with the SmtpAppender, I also need to add RollingFileAppender as well as Console appender programmatically.

```
package vish;

import org.apache.logging.log4j.Level;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.SmtpAppender;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.builder.api.ConfigurationBuilder;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.builder.api.ConfigurationBuilderFactory;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.builder.api.LayoutComponentBuilder;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.builder.api.RootLoggerComponentBuilder;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.builder.impl.BuiltConfiguration;

public class SmtpAppenderBuilder {

  public static void main(String[] args) {

    String pattern = "%d{MM-dd@HH\\:mm\\:ss}%-4r %-5p [%t] %37c %3x - %m%n";
    ConfigurationBuilder<BuiltConfiguration> builder = ConfigurationBuilderFactory.newConfigurationBuilder();
    LayoutComponentBuilder layoutBuilder = builder.newLayout("PatternLayout").addAttribute("pattern", pattern);

    RootLoggerComponentBuilder rootLogger = builder.newRootLogger(Level.DEBUG);
    builder.setStatusLevel(Level.DEBUG);
    org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.SmtpAppender.Builder smtpBuilder = SmtpAppender.newBuilder();
    smtpBuilder.setName("emailAppender");
    smtpBuilder.setSmtpUsername("test1@gmail.com");
    smtpBuilder.setSmtpPassword("###YpSv1925");
    smtpBuilder.setSmtpProtocol("https");
    smtpBuilder.setSmtpHost("smtp.gmail.com");
    smtpBuilder.setBufferSize(512);
    smtpBuilder.setTo("test2@gmail.com");
    smtpBuilder.setSubject("testing");
  }
}
```

How should I add the smtpAppender to the configutation  or the rootLogger ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to properly configure log4j2 programmatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53567092/how-to-properly-configure-log4j2-programmatically)

Comment: The problem I am facing is that there is no way I am able to add the smtpAppender to the rootLogger . The following line gives a compile level error ( maked as red ) :

rootLogger.add(smtpBuilder.asBuilder())

Answer (score 3):

You are mixing up two APIs:

- the [ConfigurationBuilder API](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/customconfig.html), which is the closest code equivalent to the configuration files. It only creates **definitions** of the actual logging components, the real ones are created when [`Configuration#initialize()`](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/log4j-core/apidocs/org/apache/logging/log4j/core/LifeCycle.html) is called on the configuration object. You can create the **definition** of an `SMTPAppender` like this:

  ```java
  private Configuration createConfig() {
     ConfigurationBuilder<BuiltConfiguration> builder = ConfigurationBuilderFactory.newConfigurationBuilder()//
                                                                                   .setStatusLevel(Level.DEBUG);
     LayoutComponentBuilder layoutBuilder = builder.newLayout("PatternLayout")//
                                                   .addAttribute("pattern", "%d{MM-dd@HH\\:mm\\:ss}%-4r %-5p [%t] %37c %3x - %m%n");
     AppenderComponentBuilder appenderBuilder = builder.newAppender("emailAppender", "SMTP")//
                                                       .addAttribute("smtpUsername", "test1@gmail.com")
                                                       .addAttribute("smtpPassword", "###YpSv1925")
                                                       .addAttribute("smtpProtocol", "smtps")
                                                       .addAttribute("smtpHost", "smtp.gmail.com")
                                                       .addAttribute("to", "test2@gmail.com")
                                                       .addAttribute("subject", "testing")
                                                       .add(layoutBuilder);
     AppenderRefComponentBuilder appenderRefBuilder = builder.newAppenderRef("emailAppender");
     RootLoggerComponentBuilder rootLoggerBuilder = builder.newRootLogger(Level.DEBUG)//
                                                           .add(appenderRefBuilder);
     return builder.add(appenderBuilder)//
                   .add(rootLoggerBuilder)
                   .build();
  }
  ```
- the actual builders of Log4j 2.x components, which are called by reflection by `Configuration#initialize` using the definitions above. You can also use them directly:

  ```java
  private static Configuration createConfig2() {
     return new AbstractConfiguration(null, ConfigurationSource.NULL_SOURCE) {

        @Override
        protected void doConfigure() {
           Layout<String> layout = PatternLayout.newBuilder()//
                                                .withPattern("%d{MM-dd@HH\\:mm\\:ss}%-4r %-5p [%t] %37c %3x - %m%n")
                                                .withConfiguration(this)
                                                .build();
           Appender appender = SmtpAppender.newBuilder()//
                                           .setName("emailAppender")
                                           .setSmtpUsername("test1@gmail.com")
                                           .setSmtpPassword("###YpSv1925")
                                           .setSmtpProtocol("smtps")
                                           .setTo("test2@gmail.com")
                                           .setSubject("testing")
                                           .setLayout(layout)
                                           .setConfiguration(this)
                                           .build();
           LoggerConfig rootLogger = getRootLogger();
           rootLogger.setLevel(Level.DEBUG);
           rootLogger.addAppender(appender, null, null);
        }
     };
  }
  ```

Both `Configuration`s are equivalent and you can apply them on the current context with:

```java
Configurator.reconfigure(config);
```

However they will be lost upon `Configurator.reconfigure()`, unless you define [your own `ConfigurationFactory`](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/customconfig.html#ConfigurationFactory).